# Ruby: Delete space after every comma?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

What would be the ruby code to delete whitespace after every comma in a string?
I'm not sure why this didn't work..

```
.gsub(/[, ]/, ',')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"hello, world".gsub(/, /, ',')
```

The `[]` are used to match any of the contained characters. You are replacing every comma or space with a comma.

Comment: No problem, we've all been there ;-)

Comment: also this exact operation has no need for a regexp, you could use `str.gsub(', ', ',')` instead to save some cpu cycles